# change the value of const_cast ptr/ref doesn't change the original object value?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I found a weird problem of same address with different values after change const_cast ptr/ref object value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    const auto i=123;
    auto &ref2i=i; auto ptr2i=&i;

    auto pp=const_cast<int*>(ptr2i); *pp=456;
    cout<<&i<<" with value "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<pp<<" with value "<<*pp<<endl;
    cout<<ptr2i<<" with value "<<*ptr2i<<endl;

    auto &rr=const_cast<int&>(ref2i); rr=789;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    cout<<ref2i<<endl;
    cout<<rr<<endl;
}
```

what the hell is going on?

https://paiza.io/projects/HyLGbHxD2khynpclDWJnvA?language=cpp

Output:

```
0x7ffc1b0e8b54 with value 123
0x7ffc1b0e8b54 with value 456
0x7ffc1b0e8b54 with value 456
123
789
789
```

Comment: You cannot change value of `const` object, neither with `const_cast` nor anything else. Attempting to do so results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Wow, another UB in c++? ...

Comment: There's a lot of possible UB in C++. We have a (non-exhaustive, and somewhat outdated) list here: [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you spell out the type of `ptr2i` you get:

```
const int * ptr2i = &i;  // since i is const
```

Now you can `const_cast` this `const int *` to an `int *`:

```
auto pp = const_cast<int*>(ptr2i);  // ok
```

But the pointed at variable `i` has type `const int`, so if you then try to modify this pointed at value:

```
*pp = 456;  // oops, UB since you are attempting to modify i
```

you invoke undefined behavior. This can result in a program that does anything, including showing different values at the same address.

The same restrictions apply when you cast a `const int &` to an `int &` and then try to modify it.